# Django: Complex annotation, how to avoid for loop?

Tags: python, django, django-orm

For an analytics app that utilizes Google Realtime Analytics API, I have my `models.py` definitions as follows:

```
class Report(BaseModel):
    ios_report = JSONField()
    android_report = JSONField()

class Article(BaseModel):

    internal_id = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    short_title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    picture_url = models.URLField()
    published_date = models.DateField()
    clip_link = models.URLField()
    reports = models.ManyToManyField(
        "Report", through="ArticleInReport", related_name="articles"
    )

class ArticleInReport(BaseModel):

    article = models.ForeignKey("core.Article", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='articleinreports')
    report = models.ForeignKey("core.Report", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='articleinreports')
    ios_views = models.IntegerField()
    android_views = models.IntegerField()

    @property
    def total_views(self):
        return self.ios_views + self.android_views
```

Everything starts with a `Report` object that is created at set intervals. This report contains data about articles and their respective views. A `Report` will have a relationship with an `Article` through `ArticleInReport`, which holds the total number of users in `Article` **at the time the report was imported**.

In my view, I need to display the following information:

- All articles that received views in the last 24 hours.
- With each article annotated with the following information:
- If present, the number of views the `Article` object had in the last `Report`. If not present, 0.

I'm achieving this as follows in my `views.py`:

```
reports_in_time_range = Report.objects.filter(created_date__range=[starting_range, right_now])
last_report = Report.objects.last()
unique_articles = Article.objects.filter(articleinreports__report__in=reports_in_time_range).distinct('id')

    articles = Article.objects.filter(id__in=unique_articles).distinct('id').annotate(
        total_views=Case(
                When(articleinreports__report=last_report,
                     then=(F("articleinreports__ios_views") + F("articleinreports__android_views"))), default=0, output_field=IntegerField(),
        ))

    sorted_articles = sorted(articles, key=operator.attrgetter('total_views'), reverse=True)
```

But I also need a "trend graph" for each article displayed, with the following information:

1. X axis: All reports (or rather, report dates) imported in the last 6 hours, whether the article ID appears in them or not.
2. Y axis: The value of `total_views` in each respective report: if the article is present, then display `total_views`, if not, return `0`.

**I can't find an efficient way** to do this without resorting to multiple for loops. The way I have it currently is by adding the following method to the `Article` model:

```
class Article(BaseModel):

    def get_article_data_for_reports(self, report_objs):
        graph_dict = {}
        graph_dict['x_vals'] = [x.created_date for x in report_objs]
        graph_dict['y_vals'] = []
        for passed_report in report_objs:
            try:
                graph_dict['y_vals'].append(ArticleInReport.objects.get(article=self, report=passed_report).total_views)
            except ArticleInReport.DoesNotExist:
                graph_dict['y_vals'].append(0)
        print(graph_dict)
        return graph_dict
```

and in the `views.py` file I do this:

```
    context["articles"] = sorted_articles
    context["article_graphs"] = {}

    for article in sorted_articles:
        context["article_graphs"][article.internal_id]= article.get_article_data_for_reports(xhours_ago_reports)
```

I can then somehow use this in the view's context. But before proceeding, I'm wondering if there's a better way to do this. The page loading time spiked from milliseconds to a 5-9 seconds on each refresh.

Comment: I'm not convinced that this annotation works correctly: since here you basically take the *first* (and that can be a random order) `Report` in which the `Article` appears, and you use these views. But if an `Article` appears in *multiple* `Report`s, you do not sum up the views.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I'm not sure what you mean. Are you talking about the first annotation, or the second? Also, I don't need to sum up anything. I only need to display the LATEST `total_views` data for an article, alongside the trend graph.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem in any case my bigger problem is the for loop, which I'm not sure how to solve with faster methods.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I've fixed the distinct issue. If you have any insights on avoiding the for loop that would be great.

Comment: I had similar problems I used two things: 
1. making a view in Postgres and reducing complex query. The views tables work like normal models in with code tweak in the model which I am sure is available in the documentation
2. I used redis to cache my data for 24 hours.
refer: http://schinckel.net/2014/09/01/postgres-view-meet-django-model/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from django.db.models import F


reports = Report.objects.all()  # Filter reports here

# This creates LEFT OUTER JOIN with all ArticleInReport, so each
# Article will appear in result once per each report which includes it
articles_with_reports = Article.objects.annotate(
    report_id=F('articleinreports__report_id')
)
# We are only interested in some reports
articles_in_reports = articles_with_reports.filter(
    report_id__in=reports.values('id')
)
# As each result row is actually ArticleInReport, this effectively gives
# amount of views per article per report
articles_with_views = articles_in_reports.annotate(
    views=(
            F('articleinreports__ios_views')
            + F('articleinreports__android_views')
    )
)
# Now do some processing in python - it's cheap
# We need dictionary to create final chart data
articles_map = {}  # {Article: {report_id: article_with_view}}
for article in articles_with_views:
    articles_map.setdefault(article, {})
    articles_map[article][article.report_id] = article.views

article_graphs = {}
# Force-evaluate to cache Reports
# Actually this would happen automatically, but to be certain...
reports = list(reports)
# As we want all Articles, we have to fetch them
for article in Article.objects.all():
    x_vals = []
    y_vals = []
    # Now for each report we will set article.views or 0
    # this will execute only once
    for report in reports:
        x_vals.append(report.created_date)
        if (
            article in articles_map
            and report.id in articles_map[article]
        ):
            # We have views for this article in this record
            y_vals.append(articles_map[article][report.id])
        else:
            # Defaults
            y_vals.append(0)
    article_graphs[article] = {
        'x_vals': x_vals,
        'y_vals': y_vals
    }

# Finally, we have article_graphs
# {
#    Article: {
#        'x_vals': [Date, Date, Date],
#        'y_vals': [100, 0, 50]
#    },
#    ....
# }
```

**UPDATE**

To build graphs only for `Articles` which have at least 1 appearance in recent Report, we just wanna use `articles_map` directly

```
article_graphs = {}
# Force-evaluate to cache Reports
# Actually this would happen automatically, but to be certain...
reports = list(reports)
for article, views_by_report in articles_map.items():
    x_vals = []
    y_vals = []
    # Now for each report we will set article.views or 0
    for report in reports:
        x_vals.append(report.created_date)
        y_vals.append(views_by_report.get(report.id, 0))
    article_graphs[article] = {
        'x_vals': x_vals,
        'y_vals': y_vals
    }
```

Comment: This looks promising. I will have to test and update. One issue though: `# As we want all Articles, we have to fetch them` - we actually only need the articles that appear in reports from last X hours, the reports we're filtering for.

Comment: I also think we're querying all article objects twice here unnecessarily: again, because we only need those that appear in the reports that we're filtering for.

Comment: @zerohedge I will update it in some time, just misinterpreted your "But I also need a "trend graph" for EACH article displayed, "

Comment: thanks. In ‘articles_with_reports’, shouldn’t we filter these further to articles that appear in the reports variable we queried before? Also: are you sure ‘article_with_views’ should reference ‘article with reports’ and not ‘article_in_reports’?

Comment: @zerohedge
There are filtering (# We are only interested in some reports). Yes, you are right, is it an error, we should use articles_in_reports (so the filtering applies)

Comment: thanks for your patience. What I mean with ‘article_with_reports’, instead of loading and annotating all article objects, we filter first, and only then annotate.

Comment: @zerohedge it is no difference. As QuerySets are lazy, they will be only evaluated inside loop, before it we are just creating SQL query

Comment: one last correction - we should iterate over articles_with_views and not articles in when creating articles_map. Otherwise, a splendid answer that worked out of the box. Marked correct.

Comment: sorry to ping you, I have a simillar questions and not many people have knowledge with complex annotations. If you can have a look it'd be great: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52689949/django-complex-annotation