# Django complex annotation

Tags: django, django-orm

**Pre-requisites:**

- Queryset must return `Article`s
- Queryset must return unique objects
- Must not utilize for loops that hit the database (meaning N queries for N objects to annotate)

**my models:**

```
class Report(BaseModel):
    ios_report = JSONField()
    android_report = JSONField()

class Article(BaseModel):

    internal_id = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    short_title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    picture_url = models.URLField()
    published_date = models.DateField()
    clip_link = models.URLField()
    reports = models.ManyToManyField(
        "Report", through="ArticleInReport", related_name="articles"
    )

class ArticleInReport(BaseModel):

    article = models.ForeignKey("core.Article", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='articleinreports')
    report = models.ForeignKey("core.Report", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='articleinreports')
    ios_views = models.IntegerField()
    android_views = models.IntegerField()


    @property
    def total_views(self):
        return self.ios_views + self.android_views
```

Everything starts with a `Report` object that is created at set intervals. This report contains data about articles and their respective views. A `Report` will have a relationship with an `Article` through `ArticleInReport`, which holds the total number of users in `Article` **at the time the report was imported**.

In my view, I need to display the following information:

- All articles that received views in the last 30 minutes.
- With each article annotated with the following information, and this is where I'm facing a problem:

> If present, the number of views the `Article` object had in the *last* `Report`. If not present, 0.

**my `views.py` file:**

```
reports_in_time_range = Report.objects.filter(created_date__range=[starting_range, right_now]).order_by('created_date')

last_report = reports_in_time_range.prefetch_related('articles').last()
unique_articles = Article.objects.filter(articleinreports__report__in=reports_in_time_range).distinct('id')

articles = Article.objects.filter(id__in=unique_articles).distinct('id').annotate(
    total_views=Case(
            When(id__in=last_report.articles.values_list('id', flat=True),
                 then=F('articleinreports__ios_views') + F('articleinreports__android_views')),
            default=0, output_field=IntegerField(),
    ))
```

Some explanation for my thought process: first, get me only articles that appear in the relevant reports in the time range (`filter(id__in=unique_articles)`), return only distinct articles. Next, if the article's ID appears in the **last report**'s list of articles (through `ArticleInReport` of course), calculate iOS views + Android views for that `ArticleInReport`.

This above annotation is working for most `Article`s, but failing miserably for others for no apparent reason. I've tried many different approaches but seem to always get the wrong results.

Comment: It's very important to avoid hits to database, but not at this price. In my opinion you should to split your query in two or more queries. Splitting the query you will improve in readability and also, may be, in performance (sometimes two simple queries runs faster than a complex one)  Remember you have all the power of dics, comprehension and itertools to massage your partials results.

Comment: @daniherrera I only said avoid database hits in *for loops*, meaning N queries for N items (articles).I’ll make that clearer.

Comment: I just wrote an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very important to avoid hits to database, but not at this price. In my opinion you should to split your query in two or more queries. Splitting the query you will improve in readability and also, may be, in performance (sometimes two simple queries runs faster than a complex one) Remember you have all the power of dics, comprehension and itertools to massage your partials results.

```
reports_in_time_range = ( Report
                         .objects
                         .filter(created_date__range=[starting_range, right_now])
                         .order_by('created_date'))

last_report = reports_in_time_range.prefetch_related('articles').last()

report_articles_ids = ( Article
                       .objects
                       .filter(articleinreports__report=last_report)
                       .values_list('id', flat=True)
                       .distinct())

report_articles = ( Article
                   .objects
                   .filter(id__in=report_articles_ids)
                   .annotate( total_views=Sum(  
                                   F('articleinreports__ios_views') +
                                   F('articleinreports__android_views'),
                                   output_field=IntegerField()
                   )))

other_articles = ( Article
                   .objects
                   .exclude(id__in=report_articles_ids)
                   .annotate( total_views=ExpressionWrapper(
                                    Value(0),
                                    output_field=IntegerField())
                   )))

articles = report_articles | other_articles
```

Comment: The concept looks promising, thank you. However, shouldn’t other_articles’ filter clause be different? Also: correct me if I’m wrong but there’s an importance to the order in our `articles` assignment, right? report_articles must come before other_articles?

Comment: @zerohedge, of course, should be `exclude`. Fixed. Notice: I wrote the code without testing it.

Comment: I’ll test it soon and mark accordingly. But shouldn’t both queries also filter for `reports_in_time_range`? Since we don’t want ALL articles in the DB only those that appear in the reports in that time range..

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your approach you need to match the only exact id's using `IN` will return a larger than expected bound and you can using the reverse name directly to filter the article objects, also the excessive use of unique

```
articles_with_views_in_range = (
    Article.objects
        .annotate(
              total_views=Case(
                  When(articleinreports__range=(start_range, end_range), 
                       then=F('articleinreports__ios_views') + F('articleinreports__android_views')),
                  default=0, output_field=IntegerField(),
              )
        ).filter(total_views__gt=0)
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

I can see the problem with `then=F('articleinreports__ios_views') + F('articleinreports__android_views')`,  because it has no idea which ArticleInReport to use.... So it will probably create duplicates per each ArticleInReport associated with each Article. As @daniherrera suggests,  you can firstly get all Articles you need,  then fetch all ArticleInReport from last report,  that would be 3 queries.  Then you can just loop through Articles and if you have ArticleInReport for Article,  assign views count, if no -  assign zero. This will work if you don't need any further sql operations with `total_views`. You would probably want to build a dictionary of {Article.id: ArticleInReport}  before loop for easy lookup.

Another approach (if you need some filtering or sorting or whatever) is to use `Subquery` of ArticleInReport from last report to add `total_views` annotation for Article queryset. You can then use `Coalesce` operator to replace Null with zero when Article received no views in last Report.

P. S.  I think that `prefetch_related('articles')` is useless,  because you use values_list anyway. 
P. P. S also you don't need distinct for unique_articles and articles,  because __in lookup will already produce distinct result

Comment: thing is, I need the `Article` objects because I need to access their attributes in the view. So I need `{<Article>: ArticleInReport}` and not `{Article.id: ArticleInReport}`...is that possible?

Comment: @zerohedge You need the dictionary just to lookup `total_views` when iterating over Articles,  there is no problem in having Article object and using it`s id to find ArticleInReport by its article_id. But yes,  it's possible,  you will just have to add select_related to ArticleInReport queryset to avoid N+1