# Django: Annotate across three models

Tags: python, django, orm

I'd like to make an intricate `annotate` call over a `QuerySet` and I don't know how to build it. Could you help?

I'll try to simplify my setup:

I have 3 models: `Movie`, `Actor` and `Casting`.

Each `Casting` has a foreign key to a `Movie` and an `Actor`, and a `CharField` for `role`.

For example, a `Casting` can be that Johnny Depp played Jack Sparrow in Pirates of the Caribbean.

I'd like to get a list of movies, and to each movie there will be an annotation saying the role that Johnny Depp played in that movie. If he didn't play in that movie, it should be `None`.

Note that I'm giving a specific actor, I don't want to go over all actors.

Comment: What if an actor was casted for multiple roles in a movie?

Comment: Hehe :) Let's assume just one casting in each movie. I think it's called unique_together, which would make a great name for a movie that had the same actor play a set of identical twins :)

Comment: Not the same, but very close to: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52689949/842935

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `.annotate(..)` this with a `Case(..)` object:

```
Movie.objects.annotate(
    role=Min(Case(
        When(casting__actor=my_actor, then=F('casting__role')),
        default=None
    ))
)
```

Now the `Movie` objects will have an attribute `.role` that holds the `role` for that actor.

If there are *multiple* roles for the actor, it will take the lexicographically smallest one, if there is no such actor, it will take `None`.

Comment: Nice answer. But, I guess, It's ok for DB2, ORACLE and POSTGRESQL and fails for MARIADB/MYSQL, SQLSERVER and HSQLDB. Source: [NULL Order Behavior](https://docs.mendix.com/refguide/null-ordering-behavior)

Comment: @daniherrera: but here we are not ordering. The SQL `MIN(..)` normally *ignores* the `NULL`s, and returns `NULL` if the collection was *empty* (which it is, since as said we ignore the `NULL`). `MIN(..)` and `ORDER BY` are *not* fully equivalent.

Comment: @daniherrera: if you for example in MySQL make a table with `NULL`s and values, then the `NULL`s are ignored if you make a `SELECT MIN(column) FROM table`.

Comment: wow. my bad. You are right! Cood's rule 3 [Systematic treatment of null values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codd%27s_12_rules)